# No response for XHR request in python with requests.post()

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I want to replicate a one-page post request, I have tried but I don't get the same response, if someone could help me I am very new.

GENERAL:

```
Request URL: https://moredrops.cl/cart/add
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200
```

RESPONSE HEADERS:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Date: Thu, 19 Nov 2020 02:04:22 GMT
Server: *
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: es-CL
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Encoding: gzip
Set-Cookie: anonymous-consents=%5B%5D; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Fri, 19-Nov-2021 02:04:21 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: dropsb2cstore-cart=d3b69c3a-e5eb-4fe9-8264-ca3124c2cb7b; Max-Age=360000000; Expires=Fri, 16-Apr-2032 18:04:21 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Content-Length: 828
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=95
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

REQUESTS HEADERS:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: es-US,es-419;q=0.9,es;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 83
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie: anonymous-consents=%5B%5D; cookie-notification=NOT_ACCEPTED; ROUTE=.accstorefront-6948d98dcc-9kg2g; __utma=140877358.2147208320.1605750829.1605750829.1605750829.1; __utmc=140877358; __utmz=140877358.1605750829.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); JSESSIONID=Y11-e1b15c4c-3d3e-446c-9f14-e858434f2e93.accstorefront-6948d98dcc-9kg2g; dropsb2cstore-cart=d3b69c3a-e5eb-4fe9-8264-ca3124c2cb7b; __utmt=1; __utmb=140877358.7.9.1605751158440
Host: moredrops.cl
Origin: https://moredrops.cl
Referer: https://moredrops.cl/Drops/Woman/Footwear/Sneakers/Zapatilla-Nike-Wmns-Dunk-Low-Disrupt-Black-Fossil-Gum/p/NICK6654002090
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

FORM-DATA:

```
qty: 1
productCodePost: NICK6654002090
CSRFToken: none
```

RESPONSE:

```
{"quickOrderErrorData": [

],

"cartAnalyticsData":{"cartCode" : "01198176","productPostPrice":"82990.0","productName":"Zapatilla Nike Wmns Dunk Low Disrupt Black/Fossil/Gum"}
,
"addToCartLayer":"\u003Cdiv id=\"addToCartLayer\" class=\"add-to-cart\"\u003E\n            \u003Cdiv class=\"cart_popup_error_msg\"\u003E\n                \u003C\/div\u003E\n\n            \u003Cdiv class=\"add-to-cart-item\"\u003E\n\t\t\u003Cdiv class=\"thumb\"\u003E\n\t\t\t\u003Ca href=\"\/Drops\/Woman\/Footwear\/Sneakers\/Zapatilla-Nike-Wmns-Dunk-Low-Disrupt-Black-Fossil-Gum\/p\/NICK6654002090\"\u003E\n\t\t\t\t\u003Cimg src=\"\/medias\/DROPS-NICK6654002-VIEW1.jpg-300Wx300H?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3w1Njg4fGltYWdlL2pwZWd8aDk1L2g2Zi84ODkxNzAyMzEyOTkwL0RST1BTX05JQ0s2NjU0MDAyX1ZJRVcxLmpwZ18zMDBXeDMwMEh8OWQxN2NiNjE0ODc0YmNjYzBjZjJkYjQ5ZjFkODAwMTMwODJjY2Q5MGM3MzhhNDdlYTYzMjMzMmVjODc4OGFhNw\" alt=\"Zapatilla Nike Wmns Dunk Low Disrupt Black\/Fossil\/Gum\" title=\"Zapatilla Nike Wmns Dunk Low Disrupt Black\/Fossil\/Gum\"\/\u003E\n\t\t\t\u003C\/a\u003E\n\t\t\u003C\/div\u003E\n\t\t\u003Cdiv class=\"details\"\u003E\n\t\t\t\u003Ca class=\"name\" href=\"\/Drops\/Woman\/Footwear\/Sneakers\/Zapatilla-Nike-Wmns-Dunk-Low-Disrupt-Black-Fossil-Gum\/p\/NICK6654002090\"\u003EZapatilla Nike Wmns Dunk Low Disrupt Black\/Fossil\/Gum\u003C\/a\u003E\n\t\t\t\u003Cdiv class=\"qty\"\u003E\u003Cspan\u003ECantidad agregada\u003C\/span\u003E&nbsp;1\u003C\/div\u003E\n\t\t\t\u003Cdiv class=\"itemSize\"\u003E\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003Cspan class=\"label\"\u003ETalla\u003C\/span\u003E\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t9 USA WMNS\u003C\/div\u003E\n\t\t\t\t\t\u003Cdiv class=\"item--price\"\u003E\n\t\t\t\t\t\t$82.990\u003C\/div\u003E\n\t\t\t\t\u003C\/div\u003E\n    \u003C\/div\u003E\u003Ca href=\"\/cart\" class=\"btn btn-primary btn-block add-to-cart-button\"\u003E\n\t                Ver Carro\u003C\/a\u003E\n            \u003Ca href=\"\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-block js-mini-cart-close-button\"\u003E\n                Seguir Comprando\u003C\/a\u003E\n\t\t\u003C\/div\u003E\n\t"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
# importing the requests library 
import requests 

# defining the api-endpoint 
API_ENDPOINT = "https://moredrops.cl/cart/add"

# data to be sent to api 
data = {
    'qty': 1,
    'productCodePost': 'NICK6654002090',
    'CSRFToken': None
}

# sending post request and saving response as response object 
r = requests.post(url=API_ENDPOINT, data=data) 

print(f"The results is: {r.text}")
```